# Laravel 5.2 not working with vagrant homestead php 7

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

**System & Tools:**

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
- vagrant_1.8.1_x86_64
- virtualbox-5.0_5.0.12-104815~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64
- (**VM**) https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead-7/versions/0.2.1/providers/virtualbox.box

Im having problem with laravel & vagrant setup. The same setups used to work with laravel 5.1 but now with 5.2 its stopped working.
When I open the URL `http://laravel.app` it redirect to my localhost page not laravel app.

But if i do `http://laravel.app:8000/` it gives `Unable to connect` firefox can't establish a connection to the server at laravel.app:8000.

Please guide me what i'm doing wrong. i'm new to laravel and vagrant and did managed to run 5.1 few weeks ago but now 5.2 is stcuk with virtualbox php 7

**Instructions followed from laravel site:**

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

---

**~.homestead/Homestead.yaml**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/www/sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   raven
192.168.10.10   laravel.app

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**Forwarding ports...**

```
default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Wader for helping me out. With his help I found the problem.
Coming from Windows user experience the case sensitive names got me this time.

The homestead.yaml file had `Laravel` as site directory while my directory name was in lower case `laravel`. I capitalised the directory and it worked. Along with the IP change and appending the port as suggested by @Warden

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/hosts` file should point your domain to `127.0.0.1`, this is because homestead forwards `127.0.0.1:8000` to port `80` on your vagrant box. In this case `192.168.10.10:80`.

So your `/etc/hosts` should look like this

```
127.0.0.1    laravel.app
```

In your browser you should then access `http://laravel.app:8000/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Now following your instruction, i get the error: `No input file specified`. when i ping to the address it says: `unknown host`

Comment: Okay, thats progress, at least now you're connecting to the homestead box. Just to check you do have your Laravel installation in `~/www/sites/Laravel/` on your host machine?

Comment: yes i made a laravel new laravel in that directory. The project is in `home/www/sites/laravel`

Comment: Okay, and can you see the contents of that folder in `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/` if you ssh into the homestead box?

Comment: yes ssh into vagrant and the content is there in `/home/vagrant/Code/laravel`

Comment: Try running `homestead provision` to ensure the vhost is updated.

Comment: @Bsienn OPs `laravel.app` document root is set to `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public` so there should be no need to manually add `/public` onto the URL. If you did need to do that I'd classify that as being broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99612/discussion-between-bsienn-and-wader).

Answer (score 0):

Try placing

---

box: laravel/homestead-7

at the top of your homestead.yaml file

Then in terminal enter homestead ssh

then type in serve laravel.app /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public

Comment: With or without `box: laravel/homestead-7` it works. Thanks for your input